# Getting submatches when the regex match with a larger string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match a pattern in a Java string (a json one). This pattern matches in the string several times, but it also matches with a string that contains the others.
Let me explain myself with an example.

```
    String json = "IRRELEVANT_TEXT{'/element|1717_todossavoy/480/': {item_url:'/element|1717_Lorem/64/', item_description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'},'/element|1717_Marcrie/480/': {item_url:'/element|1717_Vestibulum/64/', item_description: ' Vestibulum enim tellus, sodales sit amet consequat ut'},'/element|1717_Cannes05/434/': {item_url:'/element|1717_Nullam/64/', item_description: 'Nullam gravida risus vehicula nisi egestas'},'/element|1717_babelsavoy/266/': {item_url:'/element|1717_Pellentesque/64/', item_description: 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus'}};IRRELEVANT";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("/element.*480/").matcher(json);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

I am getting the following:

```
/element|1717_todossavoy/480/': {item_url:'/element|1717_Lorem/64/', item_description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'},'/element|1717_Marcrie/480/
```

But I'd like to get the 2 following keys:

```
/element|1717_todossavoy/480/
/element|1717_Marcrie/480/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thats beacause of greedy regexps. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2301298/891391

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.*` is *greedy* and will try to match *as much as possible*.  You can make it reluctant/ungreedy by appending a question mark.  `.*?`.

However, this *still* won't give you what you want because `/element|1717_Lorem/64/` will match up to `480`.  A better regex would probably be

```
/element[^/]+/480/
```

Comment: Thank for your response. That saved my day and it is really understable :)